# Why the upload cancels and the server close the connection

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, file-upload

I am uploading a video file of 14 megabytes, this is my configs:

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", "180");
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "300M");
ini_set("post_max_size", "300M");
ini_set("memory_limit", "300M");
```

i have puted that in index.php file and my .htaccess:

```
addDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So the problem is that when i upload a video file, in the status bar i see percent incrementing 1%, 2%, 3%, 4%, 5%, 6%, 7%, 8%, 9%, 10%, 11%, 12%, 13$, 14%, 15%... etc..

and when it reaches 19-20% - it cancels to 0%, and then again starts to increment 1%, 2%, 3%, i can't understand why is happening that? can someone explain me? do you had something like this? how can this be fixed?, the file is about 14 megabytes....

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>title</p>
<input type="text" name="title">
<p>video file</p>
<input type="file" name="video">
<p>cover file</p>
<input type="file" name="pic">
<p>description</p>
<textarea name="short_desc" style="width: 500px; height: 150px;"></textarea>
<p><input type="submit" value="add video" name="add"></p>
</form>
```

this is the html upload form...

and this is the upload method in codeIgniter:

```
public function add_video()
{

    if(!$this->is_admin){return false;}

    if(!$this->input->post('add')){
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view(ADMIN.'video/add', null, true);
    $this->load->view(ADMIN.'layout', $data);
    }
    else
    {

        $num = 1;
        if(is_dir("./uploads/videos/video".$num))
        {

            while(true)
            {
                $num++;
                if(!is_dir("./uploads/videos/video".$num))
                {

                    mkdir("./uploads/videos/video".$num);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

            mkdir("./uploads/videos/video".$num);
        }


    $config['upload_path'] = "./uploads/videos/video".$num;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'mov|mpeg|mp3|mp4|avi|flv';;
    $config['max_size'] = '0';
    $config['max_width']  = '0';
    $config['max_height']  = '0';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('video'))
    {

         $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
         $file_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];

         $video_path = "./uploads/videos/video".$num.'/'.$file_name;
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif|bmp';
         $this->upload->initialize($config);
         if ($this->upload->do_upload('pic'))
         {

             $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
             $file_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
             $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
             $config['source_image'] = "./uploads/videos/video".$num.'/'.$file_name;
             $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
             $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
             $config['width'] = 150;
             $config['height'] = 100;

             $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

             $this->image_lib->resize();

             $image_path = $config['source_image'];



         }
         else
         {
            redirect(base_url().'admin/add_video');

         }
    }
    else
    {
        redirect(base_url().'admin/add_video');
    }
    $data = array();

    $data['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
    $data['short_desc'] = strip_tags($this->input->post('short_desc'));
    $data['video_path'] = $video_path;
    $data['image_path'] = $image_path;
    $data['date'] = date('y-m-d h:i:s');
    $this->load->model('video_model');
    $this->video_model->add($data);

    redirect(base_url().'admin/add_video');


    }

}
```

sorry for to much code, but can you some bug here that cause that problem?

Comment: some ideas?? it is happening in my hosting, but in my local machine it uploads well, i can't figure out whats going on

Comment: Check memory_limit setting too, uploaded files stored in memory while uploading.

Comment: Is it failing after 3 minutes? `ini_set("max_execution_time", "180");` maybe should be larger?

Comment: but its a file about 14 megabytes i don't think that it need to be uploaded to much time, the internet speed is fast enough, i have upated the code can you see there some bug please?, okay now i will check the memory limit too, thanks!

Comment: i have added the memory limit config with value 300M, but that doesn't helped, any other ideas?

Comment: Just confirm the bandwidth and speed with your hosting provider and change the values accordingly! :) You might need to set a limit for the upload file size.

Comment: 20% of a 14MB file in 3 minutes would be about a 127kbps upload rate. Your PHP code is probably irrelevant. I don't know how your progress bar works, but your PHP won't actually run until the file upload is complete.

Comment: @MisterPHP, your broadband doesn't seems stable. I mean it is continuously connecting/disconnecting. Try uploading same file in other Gmail/file hosting etc it will be confirmed.

Comment: but why it doesn't upload until the end?? why every time it cancels when the progress is about 20%, what can be doing this??

Comment: soooo....i as far i understand i need to tell to the provider to increase the bandwidth?

Comment: Your host may be blocking the ini_set functions. It sounds like your file is getting to about 3 megs and giving up. That seems like the kind of hard limit a sys admin might put on a shared host.

Comment: thank you very much!!!, so i will try to confirm all those settings with the host

Comment: It could be that the upload limit is set in Apache. Have you tried LimitRequestBody http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Comment: i have set that in .htaccess file, but anyway, its cancels the upload if the file is TOO BIG, so 14 megabytes, is canceling in 20% of upload to zero(0%), looks like its the host problem

Comment: Does cancel at 40% if you upload a 7 meg file?

Comment: So i found the problem, the hoster was blocking the ini_set function for the upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, memory_limit - those configs cannot be changed from the .htaccess or the ini_set, so only the host can make those changes...

Comment: @MisterPHP, not the host, the PHP RTS.  These are **PHP_INI_PERDIR** which means that ini_set can't be used.  But hosters do configure shared services for "fair use". Use FTP is its an admin function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your ini_set() even work? Trying echoing the ini_set() everytime you call it. If it sets the value, it will return the old value (will return false if it could not set the new value).

Also try testing with  :

```
set_time_limit(0);  // it will make the time limit unlimited
```